# Irish cream liqueur

Tags: drinks

Is the protein powder used in Irish cream liquor made with seaweed and is the caramel coloring made with wheat? I have celiac disease and these answers are very important to me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you have a specific brand you're talking about? Each brand may be different.

Comment: The only way to get a reliable answer is to **ask the manufacturer of the *specific* liquor**. We can - at best - give answers that start with "Most Irish cream ..." or "Typically...". As your health depends on the answer, I suggest you ask those who must know for sure.

Comment: And if you have the answers, you may actually answer your own question (including the brand and the date) here, so that future readers might perhaps also benefit from your research! Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Have you taken the [tour] and browsed our [help] yet?

Comment: With many drinks the manufacturers don't release a full list of ingredients. If you're specifically talking about Bailey's then they don't, so you'll never know. Of course, there are many brands of cream liqueur so a full list for some might be available.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think specifically that the protein powder might be made with seaweed (carageenan?) and the colouring with wheat?

Answer (score 3):

Having made Irish Cream and now [reviewing several recipes online](https://www.google.com/search?q=irish%20cream%20recipe&oq=irish%20cream%20rec&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.4406j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) just to check, including the ingredient list for the more popular brands (esp. [Bailey's](http://www.baileys.com/en-us/product_company_information.html)) I have found NONE that contain 'protein powder' (seaweed based or otherwise). The home recipes commonly omit any caramel coloring and the manufacturers provide no further details beyond "caramel coloring". 
The [Bailey's site](http://www.baileys.com/en-us/product_company_information.html) does contain some allergen information, but doesn't even list wheat as a concern...read into that what you will. The do say:

> If you are a person with a serious food allergy, you should consult your doctor before consuming Baileys. Your doctor can then contact us for a more detailed list of component ingredients if required.